# Change image dynamically on the basis of its size specified in attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am building a **CMS system** where user can manage and upload image to show on blog.

For efficiency, I am creating three versions of images for different size. But the end user has no knowledge of it.

What I want is when on **wyswyg editor** users changes its dimensions, the image *URL* should be changed accordingly to fit "icon", "thumbs" , "large" types of image. I can do that via parsing the contents on server side, but isn't there any standard way of doing it on client side?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your image has an url like so:
`http://example.com/image.jpg`

you could do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
        var src = $(this).attr('src');

        //the extension of the image (e.g. png, gif, jpeg)
        var extension = src.substr( (src.lastIndexOf('.') +1) );

        //the path to the image, without the extension (and without the . )
        var path = href.substr(0, href.length - extension.length - 1);

        //we will store our new path here
        var newSrc = '';

        //get the correct path, depending on the size of the image
        if($(this).width() < 150){
            newSrc = path + '-icon.' + extension;
        }

        if($(this).width() < 350){
            newSrc = path + '-thumb.' + extension;
        }

        if($(this).width() > 350){
            newSrc = path + '-full.' + extension;
        }

        //give our image the new image path, to either an icon, thumb or full image
        $(this).attr('src', newSrc);
    }
});
```

Comment: What about the tradeoff between .. is the image loaded first or the document.ready is called first . secondly what about the images that will be called dynamically via ajax. And most importantly ... is this type of method used .. what is better to handle it in server side or client side ???

Comment: Sorry, that would be beyond my knowledge.